# Parcelable issue

Tags: android, arraylist, parcelable

I have an ObjectOfRoutes class which has variables and their get set methods and i also have a DirectionParser class which i parse the web service and set the ObjectOfRoutes objects into an arraylist(ArrayList) and i want to pass that arraylist to another activity when i click the each listview row.(I parse the webservice in an asynctask and i execute it in onItemClick() function of listview) I try that ObjectOfRoutes implements Parcelable but the extra of intent  says the arrayList is null when i debugging.

Can anyone help?

Comment: Can you show us some code that we can help you with?

Comment: I posted the codes can you look ?

Answer (score 0):

ObjectOfRoutes

```
public class ObjectsOfResults {

private String name;
public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}


private String vicinity;
public String getVicinity() {
    return vicinity;
}

public void setVicinity(String vicinity) {
    this.vicinity = vicinity;
}


private String type;
public String getType() {
    return type;
}

public void setType(String type) {
    this.type = type;
}


private String geometry;
public String getGeometry() {
    return geometry;
}

public void setGeometry(String geometry) {
    this.geometry = geometry;
}


private String location;
public String getLocation() {
    return location;
}

public void setLocation(String location) {
    this.location = location;
}

private double lat;
public double getLat() {
    return lat;
}

public void setLat(double lat) {
    this.lat = lat;
}

private double lng;
public double getLng() {
    return lng;
}

public void setLng(double lng) {
    this.lng = lng;
}

private String icon;
public String getIcon() {
    return icon;
}

public void setIcon(String icon) {
    this.icon = icon;
}


private String reference;
public String getReference() {
    return reference;
}

public void setReference(String reference) {
    this.reference = reference;
}

private String id;
public String getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(String id) {
    this.id = id;
}


private String place_id;
public String getPlace_id() {
    return place_id;
}

public void setPlace_id(String place_id) {
    this.place_id = place_id;
}

private String scope;
public String getScope() {
    return scope;
}

public void setScope(String scope) {
    this.scope = scope;
}

private String status;
public String getStatus() {
    return status;
}

public void setStatus(String status) {
    this.status = status;
}
}



public class DirectionsParser {

public static int stepsLength;

public ArrayList<ObjectsOfRoutes> putObjintoArrayList(String url){


    ArrayList<ObjectsOfRoutes> routesList=new ArrayList<ObjectsOfRoutes>();

    JSONObject jsonObject=getJSONObjectFromUrl(url);
    ObjectsOfRoutes routesObject=new ObjectsOfRoutes();

    try {
        JSONArray jsonArray=jsonObject.getJSONArray(Constants.ROUTES);

        System.out.println("uuuuuuuuuuuuuu"+jsonArray.length());
        JSONObject jObject=jsonArray.getJSONObject(0);

        routesObject.setOvwPolyPoints(jObject.getJSONObject(Constants.OVERVIEW_POLYLINE)
                .getString(Constants.POINTS));
        System.out.println(routesObject.getOvwPolyPoints());

        routesObject.setSummary(jObject.getString(Constants.SUMMARY));
        System.out.println("Summary:"+routesObject.getSummary());

         JSONArray jArray=jObject.getJSONArray(Constants.LEGS);
         JSONObject jObject1=jArray.getJSONObject(0);

         routesObject.setlDistanceText(jObject1.getJSONObject(Constants.DISTANCE).getString(Constants.TEXT));
         System.out.println(routesObject.getlDistanceText());
         routesObject.setlDurationText(jObject1.getJSONObject(Constants.DURATION).getString(Constants.TEXT));
         System.out.println(routesObject.getlDurationText());
         routesObject.setEndAddress(jObject1.getString(Constants.END_ADDRESS));
         routesObject.setEndLocLat(jObject1.getJSONObject(Constants.END_LOCATION).getDouble(Constants.LATITUDE));
         routesObject.setEndLocLng(jObject1.getJSONObject(Constants.END_LOCATION).getDouble(Constants.LONGITUDE));
         routesObject.setStartAddress(jObject1.getString(Constants.START_ADDRESS));
         routesObject.setlStartLocLat(jObject1.getJSONObject(Constants.START_LOCATION).getDouble(Constants.LATITUDE));
         routesObject.setlStartLocLng(jObject1.getJSONObject(Constants.START_LOCATION).getDouble(Constants.LONGITUDE));



         JSONArray stepsArray =jObject1.getJSONArray(Constants.STEPS);
         ArrayList<JSONObject> stepsJObjectList=new ArrayList<JSONObject>();

         for(int x=0;x<stepsArray.length();x++){

             stepsJObjectList.add(stepsArray.getJSONObject(x));

             ObjectsOfRoutes stepsObject=new ObjectsOfRoutes();

             stepsObject.setsDistanceText(stepsJObjectList.get(x)
                     .getJSONObject(Constants.DISTANCE).getString(Constants.TEXT));
             System.out.println(stepsObject.getsDistanceText());

             stepsObject.setsDurationText(stepsJObjectList.get(x)
                     .getJSONObject(Constants.DURATION).getString(Constants.TEXT));
             System.out.println(stepsObject.getsDurationText());

             stepsObject.setsEndLocationLat(stepsJObjectList.get(x)
                     .getJSONObject(Constants.END_LOCATION).getDouble(Constants.LATITUDE));
             System.out.println(stepsObject.getsEndLocationLat());

             stepsObject.setsEndLocationLng(stepsJObjectList.get(x)
                     .getJSONObject(Constants.END_LOCATION).getDouble(Constants.LONGITUDE));
             System.out.println(stepsObject.getsEndLocationLng());

             stepsObject.setsHtml_instructions(stepsJObjectList.get(x)
                     .getString(Constants.HTML_INSTRUCTIONS).replaceAll("<[^>]*>", ""));
             System.out.println(stepsObject.getsHtml_instructions());

             stepsObject.setsPoints(stepsJObjectList.get(x)
                     .getJSONObject(Constants.POLYLINE).getString(Constants.POINTS));
             System.out.println(stepsObject.getsPoints());

             stepsObject.setsStartLocLat(stepsJObjectList.get(x)
                     .getJSONObject(Constants.START_LOCATION).getDouble(Constants.LATITUDE));
             System.out.println("start Lat:"+stepsObject.getsStartLocLat());

             stepsObject.setsStartLocLng(stepsJObjectList.get(x)
                     .getJSONObject(Constants.START_LOCATION).getDouble(Constants.LONGITUDE));
             System.out.println("start longi:"+stepsObject.getsStartLocLng());

             stepsObject.setsTravelMode(stepsJObjectList.get(x).getString(Constants.TRAVEL_MODE));
             System.out.println("travel mode:"+stepsObject.getsTravelMode());

             routesList.add(stepsObject);

         }

         stepsLength=stepsArray.length();
         System.out.println("STEPSSS"+stepsLength);

    } catch (JSONException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return routesList;

}

public String readAll(Reader reader){
    StringBuilder sBuilder=new StringBuilder();
    int cp;
    try {
        while((cp=reader.read())!=-1){
            sBuilder.append((char)cp);
        }

    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return sBuilder.toString();
}

public JSONObject getJSONObjectFromUrl(String url){

    JSONObject jsonObject=null;

    try {
        InputStream inputStream = new URL(url).openStream();
    BufferedReader bufferedReader=
            new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream,Charset.forName("UTF-8")));
    String jsonText=readAll(bufferedReader);
    jsonObject=new JSONObject(jsonText);
    }catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } 

    return jsonObject;

  }


}


  public class AVMActivity extends Activity {

ListView listViewOfAvm;
double lat;
double longi;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.avm_activity_layout);
    listViewOfAvm=(ListView)findViewById(R.id.listOfAvm);
    LoadingPlacesDataFromJson loading=new LoadingPlacesDataFromJson();

    Bundle extras=getIntent().getExtras();
    lat=extras.getDouble("latitude");
    longi=extras.getDouble("longitude");
    String keyword=extras.getString("keyword");
    loading.execute("https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/search/json?keyword="+keyword+"&location="+lat+","+longi+"&radius=3000&key=API_KEY");

    listViewOfAvm.setOnItemClickListener(loading);

}

private class LoadingPlacesDataFromJson extends AsyncTask<String , Void, ArrayList<ObjectsOfResults>>
                                                implements ListView.OnItemClickListener{

    double directionsLat;
    double directionsLng;
    ProgressDialog pDialog;
    ArrayList<ObjectsOfResults> arrayListPlaces;
    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    pDialog=ProgressDialog.show(AVMActivity.this, "Lutfen Bekleyin!!!", "Avmler Yukleniyor...");
    }

    @Override
    protected ArrayList<ObjectsOfResults> doInBackground(String... params) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
     JSONParser jParser=new JSONParser();
    return jParser.putObjintoArrayList(params[0]);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(ArrayList<ObjectsOfResults> result) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        listViewOfAvm.setAdapter(new AVMListViewAdapter(getApplicationContext(), result));
        pDialog.dismiss();
        arrayListPlaces=result;
    }

    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position,
            long arg3) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        directionsLat=arrayListPlaces.get(position).getLat();
        directionsLng= arrayListPlaces.get(position).getLng();
        LoadingDirectionsData loadingDirections=new LoadingDirectionsData();
        loadingDirections.execute("https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/json?origin="+lat+","+longi+"&destination="+directionsLat+","+directionsLng+"&language=tr&key=API_KEY");
        Intent intent=new Intent(getApplicationContext(),LocationViewWithVicinity.class);
        intent.putExtra(Constants.LATITUDE, arrayListPlaces.get(position).getLat());
        intent.putExtra(Constants.LONGITUDE, arrayListPlaces.get(position).getLng());
        intent.putExtra(Constants.VICINITY, arrayListPlaces.get(position).getVicinity());

        intent.putExtra("HTML", loadingDirections.arrayList.get(position).getsHtml_instructions());
        startActivity(intent);

    }

}

private class LoadingDirectionsData extends AsyncTask<String, Void,ArrayList<ObjectsOfRoutes>>
                                        {
    DirectionsParser directionParser;
    ArrayList<ObjectsOfRoutes> arrayList;
    @Override
    protected ArrayList<ObjectsOfRoutes> doInBackground(String... params) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
         directionParser=new DirectionsParser();
         arrayList =directionParser.putObjintoArrayList(params[0]);



         return arrayList;
    }


   }
 }
```

Comment: I try to pass in onItemClick() intent.putParcelableArrayList("arrayList",loadingDirecitons.arrayList); and recieve in LocationViewWithVicinity class but it returns null

Answer (score 0):

Implement the model class with Serializable.
That is make the class ObjectsOfResults as Serializable

You can pass the arraylist like this

intent.putExtra("array", arraylist);

And you can retrieve the same in other activity like this

getIntent().getSerializableExtra("array");

Comment: after implement serializable whath should i do can you explain a little more

Comment: are you sure the arraylist is not null. Check that first

Comment: i control that ı am sure it has values which i want to pass to another activity

Comment: You can pass the model object using the putExtra method. i.putExtra("model", modelObject);

Comment: but i pass more than one objects which are type ObjectsOfRoutes and so i want to add them into an arraylist and pass that arraylist to the activity

Comment: Hey guys, directly passing ArrayList to putExtra method is not a good idea. Although ArrayList implements serializable android OS will not serialize the whole list but instead it will serialize one list item at the time. This has performance and object reference consequences. You are better off creating wrapper class to wrap the array list in. For more info see http://nemanjakovacevic.net/blog/english/2015/03/24/yet-another-post-on-serializable-vs-parcelable/

Answer (score 0):

I'm having difficulties understanding your question exactly but you can find an example of passing an ArrayList between activities in this [test project](https://github.com/nemanja-kovacevic/Parcel-Experiment).